# Can I call @RequestMapping(SpringMVC @Controller, not spring @Service etc) from JSF view(.xhtml)?

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc

Can I use JSF(PrimeFaces - only for front end) and SpringMVC(`@RequestMapping`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Persistance`, AOP etc - for complete backend)?

How will the flow be?

```
.xhtml(primefaces JSF)->ManagedBean(JSF)->@RequestMapping(SpringMVC Controller)
->@Service(Spring)-@Persistance(Spring)->@Entity->DB
```

What will be the best practice and EA flow architecture?

In short, can I call `@RequestMapping(SpringMVC Controller)` from JSF view(PrimeFaces - .xhtml) directly, or we need some more JSF view layer components in between these such as `@ManagedBean` etc etc?

Note: I want to call `@RequestMapping` (which is RESTful `@Controller` and not Spring `@Service` or other layer) from JSF view(.xhtml)

Comment: Choose either of them - Spring MVC or JSF which you are interested in. Since both of them are MVC frameworks, using both of them together does not make sense.

Comment: True, but i want to use JSF UI Libraries(Primefaces) bcos it is a Java-Based-RIA for front end of a EA application. If i go with SpringMVC then which Java-Based-RIA technology i can use there? now my problem is if i go with SpringMVC it wont provide a RIA for view layer and if i go with JSF its not much loosely couple as spring and spring controller(@RequestMapping) gives RESTful service whereas JSF controller(@ManagedBean) doesn't provide RESTful feature. need you reply Tiny, Thanks

Comment: I want to create two separate modules(.war) for a EA application, one for frontend-UI(using JSF) and other complete backend-layers(using Spring), will it make the sense or its a stupid thing to do?

Comment: Well, what you say is choice-dependent/requirement-dependent. Everything beyond that is totally opinion-based, if you leave your choices/requirements to others and I do not want to go opinion-based anymore. I can only say that theoretically, you cannot use Spring MVC and JSF together. `Spring != Spring MVC`, If you do not know already. Spring is an enormous framework - a Java platform having several modules. Spring MVC is merely one of them allowing developers to develop web applications only. You can however, make use of Spring DI along with JSF. They are transparently usable with JSF.

Comment: Finally, if you read the preceding comment closely/carefully, you will be able to notice that it is also opinion-based that I do not think that you want to fallow.

Comment: Dear, but JSF controller(@ManagedBean) doesn't provide RESTful feature which is provided by Spring MVC controller(@RequestMapping) and other side JSF provide different RIA UI Libraries feature which is not provided by SpringMVC, so i wanted to integrate both for a EA application, Thank Tiny